# comparison of Date with nil failed - ruby

Tags: ruby

I am running a code like this:

```
if valid_from > Date.today
```

and when I run this, I get an error saying

> comparison of Date with nil failed

I assume it is happening because in some cases `valid_from` is `nil`. Is there a way to avoid getting this error?

Comment: What do you want the condition to return when `valid_from` is `nil`? Do you want `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 9):

You could do:

```
if valid_from and valid_from > Date.today
  ...
end
```

Which will short-circuit on the first clause because valid_from is nil and thus false.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to convert both to integer

```
if valid_from.to_i > Date.today.to_i
```

(nil converts to 0 and is never bigger than the current date)

The advantage is that it is shorter and doesn't need an treatment for the extra case. Disadvantage: fails in  the epoch start second (may be neglectable for a lot of scenarios)

Comment: This isn't possible (anymore): `NoMethodError (undefined method 'to_i' for Sun, 31 Jan 2021:Date)`

Answer (score 2):

I like doing them this way: `valid_from && valid_from > Date.today`